# Good Drive API usage

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-apps

I have made a google developer account from the google email provided by my organisation ( @nirmauni.ac.in email ). I have got some xxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com. I have some questions:

1. How to I browse for the files that I upload using my xxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com account. ??
2. is there any way to get myname@developer.gserviceaccount.com  email address ??

Sorry if the questions are not properly formatted.
Please ask me if you need more details :

Thanks in Advance.

( I have Googled but could not find any results )

Comment: Do you have an actual programming question? If you want to just your own email, there's no need for a service account. You should check out the [docs and samples](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/).

Comment: Heyy @Andy thanks for the reply, its ok if I don't get to use my own email address but that still what about my first question ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to I browse for the files that I upload using my
>   xxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com account. ??

You can't browse these files because it is a "Service Account"[1] not a classic google account: these type of account are useful to act as manager of cloud platforms piece like compute engine vm instances and cloud storage buckets.

> is there any way to get myname@developer.gserviceaccount.com email
>   address ??

As Andy sad, nope :)

[1] https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Comment: Sorry but I cant not find the text you are reffering to. Where in that page it is said that we can not get myname@developer.gserviceaccount.com email address.  Also can we use our own email address like as my email account user@nirmauni.ac.in ( it is a google account )

Comment: The link I posted talk about service account and their scope: they aren't for users scope; you can't have a custom service account. If you want to use Google Drive API you need to follow steps here(https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-php) using your @nirmauni.ac.in email as email for OAuth2.